# Show that the hitting time of a closed set is stopping time

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stopping-times

Let $(E,d)$ be a metric space and $B\subseteq E$ be closed, let $x:[0,\infty)\to E$, $I:=\{t\ge0:x(t)\in B\}$ and $\tau:=\inf I$. If $I$ is nonempty and $\tau\in I$, then we easily see that $$\tau\le t\Leftrightarrow\exists s\in I:s\le t\tag1$$ for all $t\ge0$. Moreover, if $I$ is nonempty and $x$ is right-continuous, then $\tau\in I$.

Now let $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ be a right-continuous $E$-valued process on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ and replace $I$ by $I:=\{t\ge0:X_t\in B\}$.

If $\omega\in\Omega$, by the aforementioned facts, either $I(\omega)=\emptyset$ (and hence $\tau(\omega)=\infty$) or $\tau(\omega)\in I(\omega)$ and hence $$\tau(\omega)\le t\Leftrightarrow\exists s\in I(\omega):s\le t\tag2.$$

From $(2)$ we see that $$\{\tau\le t\}=\bigcup_{s\in[0,\:t]}\{X_s\in B\}\tag3$$ for all $t\ge0$.

> How can we show that $$\{\tau\le t\}=\bigcup_{\substack{s\in\mathbb Q\\0\le s\le t}}\{X_s\in B\}\tag4$$ for all $t\ge00$?

By $(3)$ we only need to show that if $(\omega,s)\in\Omega\times[0,t]$, there is a $\tilde s\in\mathbb Q$ with $0\le\tilde s\le t$ and $X_{\tilde s}\in B$.

How can we do that? Clearly, if we fix $\varepsilon>0$, we can use that $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$ to find $\tilde s\in\mathbb Q$ with $|\tilde s-s|<\varepsilon$.

Now we somehow need to use that $X$ is right-continuous and a suitable characterization of closedness of $B$ ...

### **EDIT**

I've found the following proof in Kallenberg:
[image]

Our case is item (ii). While he is only claiming that $\tau_B$ is a weakly stopping time (i.e. $\{\tau_B<t\}\in\mathcal F_t$), his proof claims $\{\tau_B\le t\}\in\mathcal F_t$? Is this a typo? Would be somehow strange, since I've taken this from the third edition of the book ...

Comment: I don't think (4) is true with only right-continuity because $X$ could jump to $B$ at an irrational time $t$.

Comment: Even continuity is not enough. Think about a process which hits the boundary of $B$ at an irrational time $t$ and then leaves it again immediately.

Comment: If the process is adapted to $(\mathcal F_t)$ it is also adapted to $(\mathcal F_{t+})$. It is a common practice to replace the original filtration  $(\mathcal F_t)$ by the right- continuous filtration $(\mathcal F_{t+})$. You have to do this to prove that $\tau$ is a stopping time. As already pointed out even continuity of paths does not suffice if you use the original filtration

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you for your comment. I guess you're right, but please take a look at the proof of Kallenberg I've added to the question. Is that a typo in the book?

Comment: It does look like a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You need rigth continuity of the filtration for this. Instead of (4) use the following:

$$(\{\tau> t\})=\bigcup_{r\in\mathbb Q,t+\epsilon> r>t}\bigcap_{s<r} (\{X_s \in B^{c})$$ which belongs to $\mathcal F_{t+\epsilon}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In general, $$\{\tau\le t\}=\bigcup_{\substack{s\in\mathbb Q\\s<t}}\{\tau\le s\}.$$ So, another way to obtain the claim would be to show that $\{\tau\le s\}\in\mathcal F_s$ as long as $s$ is rational. Can we do this? I think it's possible by show a statement similar to $(1)$ and asked a separate question for this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4274689/47771. Would be great if you could take a look.